# Number of Columns a DataRowView has?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, system.data, datarowview

I have a method SelectedRow() that grabs the content of a selected DataGrid row

```
private System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRow()
{
    System.Data.DataRowView row = (System.Data.DataRowView)dgBrokerages.SelectedItems[0];
    return row;            
}
```

and would like to know how I can obtain an int containing the number of Columns that row contains.

```
private int NumColumns()
{
    System.Data.DataRowView row = SelectedRow();
    return row.Length; // <- Something like that
}
```

I'm basically looking for if there is a row.Length or row.Size?

Thanks,
iato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private int NumColumns()
{
    System.Data.DataRowView row = SelectedRow();
    return row.Row.Table.Columns.Count;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you very much :)